# Очистить массив от "on"

Tags: php

Приходит массив вида:

```
[INFRASTRUKTURA] => Array
    (
        [конференц зал] => on
        [почта] => on
        [тренажерный зал] => on
        [условия для инвалидов] => on
        [факс] => on
        [прокат авто] => on
        [обмен валюты] => on
    )

[ROOM_SERVICE] => Array
    (
        [холодильник] => on
        [сейф] => on
        [электрочайник] => on
    )

[NOMER_CLASS] => Array
    (
        [королевский] => on
        [комфорт] => on
    )

[SPA] => Array
    (
        [турецкая баня (хамам)] => on
        [джакузи] => on
        [фитнес-центр] => on
        [обертывание] => on
    )

[SPORT] => Array
    (
        [дартс] => on
        [теннис] => on
        [сквош] => on
        [боулинг] => on
    )

[SHOP] => Array
    (
        [продукты] => on
        [детские] => on
        [свой торговый центр] => on
    )
```

Как во всем массиве убрать " => on" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = array(/*ваш массив*/);
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
     foreach($array[$key] as $itemKey => $itemValue) {
           if($itemValue == 'on') {
               $array[$key][$itemKey] = '';
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: или unset($array[$key][$itemKey]);